# I can´t add the data label to my plot, occurs this Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, continuous, discrete

Hi I have this code which is working ok, but when I try show the data label I have an error that I don't know how to solve.

**Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale**

This code is ok.

```
ggplot(Datos_3.1, aes(x=reorder(Empresa, Monto), Empresa)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(y=Monto/1000000), color="blue", fill="lightblue") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(y="Monto CLP $ MM", x="", title="Ingreso por empresa, T2 2021")
```

This code have the error.

```
ggplot(Datos_3.1, aes(x=reorder(Empresa, Monto), Empresa)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(y=Monto/1000000), color="blue", fill="lightblue") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(y="Monto CLP $ MM", x="", title="Ingreso por empresa, T2 2021") + 
  geom_label(aes(label=round(Monto/1000000, digits = 0)))
```

I have the same proble if I try with geom_text()

Comment: Try with `ggplot(Datos_3.1, aes(x=reorder(Empresa, Monto), y = Monto/1000000))`.

Comment: @stefan Thanks a lot! that was so simple! now I have the data labels, just like I wanted!